# I can`t create an eclipse java class

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to open a class under a project and i keep getting the same error:
Creation of element failed. Reason: Cp65001.

I understood it has to do something with JDK version. 
So, I downloaded the eclipse update to java 13, as followed here:
[Java 13 support for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398023/java-13-support-for-eclipse)

and also tried out all the suggestion in the link below:
[How to change JDK version for an Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project)

I don't know what else i can do.
Is it recommended to use Java 11?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cp65001` is the Windows way of saying UTF-8, so it seems you're running on Windows, and that you changed the default character set to "code page 65001", and that Java / Eclipse cannot handle it.

Update the Eclipse settings to explicitly select UTF-8, by selecting pull-down menu `Window` > `Preferences`, selecting node `General` > `Workspace` and changing the `Text file encoding` to `Other: UTF-8`

If you then right-click your project and select `Properties`, select node `Resource`, you should see `Text file encoding` having value `Inherited from container (UTF-8)`. You can change it here on a project-by-project basis, instead of the global setting in the Preferences dialog, if you so choose.